# Case Statement to swap data in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL server`

**Table A**

```
GivenName                Surname
 
Mark                      Vaugh

Helen                     Michael             

                          Abc Company
                    
                          CFG Company
```

I am trying to get this output below

**OutPut**

```
GivenName        SurName

Mark              Vaugh

Helen             Michael


Abc Company       Sir/Madam

CFG Company       Sir/Madam
```

I tried to write query below but not working

```
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN a.GivenName='' then m.Surname and m.surname= 'SIr/Madam' End  As GivenName
```

Any help please

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question so that others may read it.

Comment: @Salman81 is the format ok now?

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your query like the following.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN a.GivenName = ''
            THEN a.SurName
        ELSE a.GivenName
        END AS GivenName
    ,CASE 
        WHEN a.GivenName = ''
            THEN 'Sir/Madam'
        ELSE a.Surname
        END AS Surname
FROM TABLEA a
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b68fdc/1/0)

Comment: Sir/Madam has to be in surname column

Comment: If you run the query, 'Sir/Madam ' will appear in Surname column only.

Comment: @Salman81 check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b68fdc/1/0